# getting XPath result from another XPath result

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey

I can't seem to get this to work at all. I'm trying to use an xPath result as my base query for the page from within a greasemonkey script.

The code I'm using is:

```
var select=$tag('select');
this.basePath=xpath.single("/html/body/div/div/div/div",document);
// - /html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/th[2]/a
if(select.length>0){
    this.location=xpath.single("/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/th[2]/a",this.basePath);
    console.log('location: '+this.location.singleNodeValue.textContent);
}
```

The xPath functions are:

```
var xpath=function(){
    return {
    single:function easyXPath(path,baseNode){
        if(baseNode===undefined||!isHTML(baseNode)){
                baseNode=document;
        }
        return document.evaluate(path,baseNode,null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null);
    },
    count:function easyXPathCount(path,baseNode){
        if(baseNode===undefined||!isHTML(baseNode)){
            baseNode=document;
        }
        return document.evaluate("count("+path+")",baseNode,null,XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE,null).numberValue;
    },
    number:function easyXPathNumber(path,baseNode){
        if(baseNode===undefined||!isHTML(baseNode)){
            baseNode=document;
        }
        return document.evaluate(path,baseNode,null,XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE,null).numberValue;
    },
    multi:function easyXPathMultiNode(path,baseNode){
        if(baseNode==undefined||!isHTML(baseNode)){
            baseNode=document;
        }
        return document.evaluate(path,baseNode,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
    }
};
}();
function isHTML(node){
    return node instanceof HTMLElement || node instanceof Element;
}
```

I've left the full path to the element I'm trying to reach and at last resort I will just prepend the base path to the following paths

Comment: 1) Remove `/` at the start of the path, 2) What is the value of `this` in your first snippet? If it's not inside an object method, then `this` will be `window` so assigning to `window.location` will treat the value as an URL and load it thus discarding the current page.

Comment: It is inside an object method, at this point I'm trying to get the data and set it within this method so that the parent method can evaluate it and put everything together. this.basePath will be used for further elements within the page as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it. Probably not the most efficient but it works.

```
let select=$tag('select');
this.basePath=xpath.single("/html/body/div/div/div/div");
// - /html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/th[2]/a
let fragment=document.createDocumentFragment();
let d=this.basePath.singleNodeValue.cloneNode(true);
fragment=fragment.appendChild(d);
if(select.length>0){
    this.location=xpath.single("/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/th[2]/a",fragment);
    console.log('location: '+this.location.singleNodeValue.textContent);
}
```

It seems like xPath requires a document base to work and will not work on anything that is not already a document type, or document fragment.

Hopefully this also helps someone else.